# Reading 24-Bit WAV with wavio Python 3.5

Tags: python, numpy, wav

I am using [wavio](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio/blob/master/wavio.py) by WarrenWeckesser as I need to read 24-bit wav files in python. The wav files I have are produced by some instrumentation and I am trying to get the raw values without any normalisation or scaling.

In the wavio module the code that does the work is this:

```
    if sampwidth == 3:
        a = _np.empty((num_samples, nchannels, 4), dtype=_np.uint8)
        raw_bytes = _np.fromstring(data, dtype=_np.uint8)
        a[:, :, :sampwidth] = raw_bytes.reshape(-1, nchannels, sampwidth)
        a[:, :, sampwidth:] = (a[:, :, sampwidth - 1:sampwidth] >> 7) * 255
        result = a.view('<i4').reshape(a.shape[:-1]
```

Can someone explain what it is actually doing (I am a relatively new to numpy and array slicing). I understand most of it but I don't understand what is going on here:

```
    a[:, :, sampwidth:] = (a[:, :, sampwidth - 1:sampwidth] >> 7) * 255
```

In my case it does the transform from 24 to 32 bit but I can't work out whether it is scaling the data, or simply padding it out without changing any raw values.

Comment: It does not scale or normalize the data.  It extends the sign so that the signed 24 bit data from the file can be stored as signed 32 bit data in a numpy array.  @kennytm's answer breaks it down pretty well.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much but I needed to be certain. Is it in the documentation anywhere?

Comment: The docstring does not state that `wavio.read` does not scale the data, but since the default for `wavio.write` *is* to scale the data, I guess it would be a good idea to explicitly say that `read` does not.

Comment: Here you go, Sam: https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio/commit/3c63f3d434ec80290d65084f3d1155d4d641bdcb

Comment: @Sam, here is an updated of `scipy.io.wavfile` that adds 24 bit .wav files support for read/write, access to cue markers, cue marker labels, some other metadata like pitch (if defined), etc.: [wavfile.py (enhanced)](https://gist.github.com/josephernest/3f22c5ed5dabf1815f16efa8fa53d476)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of `a` is `(num_samples, nchannels, 4)` and `sampwidth == 3`, so that line is the same as

```
a[:, :, 3:] = (a[:, :, 2:3] >> 7) * 255
```

which is the same as

```
a[:, :, 3] = (a[:, :, 2] >> 7) * 255
```

we could devectorize the outer two loops:

```
for i in range(num_samples):
    for j in range(nchannels):
        a[i, j, 3] = (a[i, j, 2] >> 7) * 255
```

The dtype of `a` is `_np.uint8`, so `a[...] >> 7` can only give out 0 when the value is <128, or 1 when it is ≥128, so the above becomes:

```
for i in range(num_samples):
    for j in range(nchannels):
        v = a[i, j, 2]
        a[i, j, 3] = 255 if v >= 128 else 0
```

If the data are 24-bit little-endian integers, this is equivalent to doing a [sign-extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) into 32-bit.